# Does the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n cos(3n)}{n^2+n}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$\sum|\frac{(-1)^n \cos(3n)}{n^2+n}| \le \sum\frac{1}{n^2+n}$
since $-1 \le cos(3n) \le 1$

$\sum\frac{1}{n^2+n} = \sum\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1})$

$\int(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}) dx = \log|x| + \log|x+1| + C$
which diverges.

Therefore by the integral test, the series diverges.

However, the answer is that the series converges absolutely. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $log|x| - log|x+1| + C$, not $log|x| + log|x+1| + C$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to say that $1/n^2-n < 1/n^2$?

Comment: Does the sum include the term for $n=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, it can be simple. If $n \geq 1$ then
$$
\bigg| \frac{(-1)^{n}\cos 3n}{n^{2}+n} \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}+n} < \frac{1}{n^{2}}.
$$
But $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges.

Comment: If n is finite and negative it is also simple.

Answer (score 3):

Of course the mistake lies in the integral test:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \log |x| + \log |x+1| \right) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1},
$$
so your antiderivative is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the absolute value of $(-1)^n\cos(3n)$ is $\leq 1$ and the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is absolutely convergent (to $1$). Moreover, since:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\log(1-x)\tag{1}$$
by taking $x=-e^{3i}$, then the real part, we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \cos(3n)}{n(n+1)} = 1-\frac{3}{2}\sin(3)-2\cos^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\log\left(2\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right).\tag{2}$$